# How prevent CSRF with crossdomain calls

Tags: php, javascript, session, csrf

Now i have situation, when javascript from example.com have access to site test1.example.com.
I did that through crossdomain and i want to prevent CSRF injection.

I thought to make this in standard way - in server side - i create hash - save hash in session
But i can't do that, because when i save hash in $_SESSION and want to check from client side - $_SESSION is empty- because its another domain (when realize that through proxy script on server side- no problem).
function check_csrf_token - always return false.

Simple code from server side

```
public function get_csrf_token(){
    $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand() . microtime()));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}


private function check_csrf_token($token){
    return ($_SESSION['token'] == $this->input->get('token'));
}
```

Comment: to clarify, the session is saved on the server, but wasn't passed to the client? or cannot be retrieved from client?

Comment: If you [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and set the domain field to `.example.com` the session will be accessible on the root and on the subdomain as well. Plus there are [non cookie-based ways](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) to pass the session ID around...

Comment: You're current CSRF validation is broken in term of security, if I just skip the page setting the cookie and post directly to the second one with an empty token, `$_SESSION['token']` and `$this->input->get('token')` will be empty and equals. This is a common validation flaw that you need  to be careful about. You should always check to make sure `$_SESSION['token']` isn't empty.

Comment: @ DaveRandom - this way don't work.
But i think in my case - i don't need prevent CSRF, because it's not CSRF in a "true sense of CSRF"